# Read/Write only permissions in Angular by route

Tags: angular, permissions, auth-guard

Currently i have the type of permission on a service and i want to set read-only by path. Is there any way to do it?
Something like the auth guard.

Thx

EDIT

Sidebar:

```
Section1
 link1p
 link2p
Section2
 link1x
 link2x
```

An example of my database response

```
Acces: Read
Section: Section1 
subSection: link1p
```

And now i want disable all forms in this component (link1p) by route, if it possible.

Comment: Please, add some relevant code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `data` property of the `Route` interface. You can pass whatever object you like to this, so utilizing it to set a read-only property is easy. Just set it up in your `Routes` array, then get it from the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` whereever you need it

```js
const routes: Routes [
    {
        path: 'myReadOnlyRoute'
        data: { readOnly: true }
    }
]
```